# Extending comparables with java generics and interfaces

Tags: java, generics, interface

So I'm creating an implementation of a priority queue using generics. I have this interface which I am trying to implement in my PriorityQueue class:

```
public interface PriorityQueueInterface<Item extends Comparable<Item>> { }
```

but I'm not sure what the proper syntax is to correctly implement the PriorityQueueInterface. Here is what I currently have:

```
public class PriorityQueue<Item extends Comparable<Item>> implements PriorityQueueInterface<Item extends Comparable<Item>>{ }
```

but it's throwing multiple errors. What would be the correct way to implement the interface? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to make the distinction between a type variable/parameter and a type argument.

Comment: for best results use `<Item extends Comparable<? super Item>>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already declared `Item` to be `Comparable<Item>` with the class definition of `PriorityQueue`.  You only need to reference it in the `implements` clause, where you don't need to repeat that it's `Comparable<Item>`.  You reference a generic type parameter in the `implements` or `extends` clause just as you would for any other part of the class body where the generic type parameter is in scope.

Try

```
public class PriorityQueue<Item extends Comparable<Item>>
    implements PriorityQueueInterface<Item>{ /* implement here */ }
```